# Conditional PostgreSQL foreign key

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to conditionally add a foreign key?

Something like:`ALTER TABLE table1 ADD FOREIGN KEY (some_id) REFERENCES other_table WHERE some_id NOT IN (0,-1) AND some_id IS NOT NULL;`

Specifically, my reference table has all positive integers (1+) but the table I need to add the foreign key to can contain zero (0), null and negative one (-1) instead, all meaning something different.

Notes:

> **I am fully aware that this is poor table design**, but it was a clever trick built 10+ years ago when the features and resources we have available at this point did not exist.  This system is running hundreds of retail stores so going back and changing the method at this point could take months which we don't have.
>
> I can not use a trigger, **this MUST be done with a foreign key**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another "shadow" column to `table1` which holds the cleaned values (i.e. everything but `0` and `-1`). Use this column for the referential integrity checks. This shadow column is updated/filled by a simple trigger on `table1` which writes all values but `0` and `-1` into the shadow column. Both `0` and `-1` could be mapped to `null`.

Then you have reference integrity and your unchanged original column. The downside: You have also a little trigger and some redundant data. But alas, this is the fate of a legacy schema!

Comment: Genius!  You are right that it is a little ugly, but the database still manages itself, so it should do the trick!

Comment: AH, have you ever worked on postgres source?  This could be a cool feature you could add by doing exactly this behind the scenes.

Comment: @trex005: I have not worked on the PG sources. But leeching on the hacker's list every now and then my impression is, that such a feature would not be welcome. If you generalize _your_ example (match anything but `0` and `-1`) and think about a generic syntax covering all possible cases you will get quite a complex syntactical construct. On the other side of the scale: There is nothing you cannot do with the existing tools already. The net result: The scarce resources (developer time/budget) will pay off better on other TODO items. But that's only my impression. Fell free to contact them.

Comment: @A.H. But PostgreSQL, like all open-source projects, is not driven by the TODO list but by the things that are actively bugging people who are willing to take them on.  While I doubt the PostgreSQL team would be willing to integrate a fix for this particular problem, I am also sure they would be willing to consider a working patch that gives PostgreSQL conditional foreign keys, if some sort of reasonable SQL syntax can be crafted to support the construct.  It would be advisable to work with the team, of course, on defining what such a syntax might be.  It's open source, working code talks.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is no, Postgres does not have *conditional* foreign keys.  Some options you might consider are:

1. Just not have a FK constraint.  Move this logic into the data access layer and live without the referential integrity.
2. Allow `NULL` in the column, which is perfectly valid even with a FK constraint.  Then, use another column to store whatever the meaning of `0` and `-1` is.
3. Add a dummy row in the referenced table for `0` and `-1`.  Even if it just had bogus data, it would satisfy the FK constraint.

Hope this helps!

Comment: These were pretty much the options I had expected.  I'll leave the question around for a while in hopes that we are wrong. :)

Comment: Option 4 is always modifying the Postgres code, it *is* open source you know :)

Comment: I mucked around with the PG source a while back to work around some corrupted data, that was quite enough for me!

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is equivalent to this check constraint:

```
create table t (a float check (a >= -1 and a = floor(a) or a is null));
```

Comment: True, but a check constraint cannot check the existence of a row in another table.

Comment: @MikeChristensen The question says the referenced table _has all positive integers (1+)_. I know that is impossible but I guess he means it has all the integers without gaps up to a certain limit. That would be covered with the addition of another condition to the check (a <= n).

Comment: Possible, I just assumed the OP actually wanted a real foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this with a check constraint and a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (some_id INT, some_id_fkey INT REFERENCES other_table(other_id), CHECK (some_id IN (0,-1) OR some_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM some_id_fkey));
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility. Use PG Inheritance to enforce a partition of the table into has +1 in the flag column and otherwise. (Usual rules/triggers for maintaining this.) Then have the FK relationship between only the Has_PLUS_ONE child table and the referenced table.

Comment: Using PG inheritance is almost never the right solution for anything. They are just too limited and quirky.

Comment: stop propagating FUD.